# Android RecyclerView pass position is always the last one

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Good day, I want to pass position from `RecyclerView`'s adapter to `MainActivity`, so I design a interface:

in RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
 publuc interface recyclerViewAdapterListener{
   void onDeviceConnect(data, position)
 }

 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   //here I call onDeviceConnect
   holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View view) {
     listener.onDeviceConnect(data, position);
   }
```

in MainActicity:

```
 private int pos;

 public void onDeviceConnect(data,position){
  pos = position; 
 }
```

I know the problem is `pos = position`, that will be always get the last position.

but I need data and position from `RecyclerView`, because when my device connected,

It will change `RecyclerView`'s item.

ex : (in MainActivity)

```
    case BleService.ACTION_NOTIFY_ON: //here my device is connected.
       updateStatus(mac,status);      //update status

    private void updateStatus(mac,status){
       Adapter.updateItem(data, pos);   //call adapter's item
    }
```

ex : (in RecyclerViewAdapter)

```
   public void updateItem(data,pos){
     if (dataList.size() != 0){
          dataList.set(pos, data);
          notifyItemChanged(pos);
   }
```

is any good idea can fix it , Thanks.

Comment: where you call the `onDeviceConnect` on your adapter ?

Comment: No need to callback to MainActivity. You can call `updateItem` directly in adapter

Comment: @ Shay Kin : I call onDeviceConnect in RecyclerViewAdapter onBindViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

in MainActicity:

`

```
public class MainActicity extends AppCompatActivity implements YourRecyleAdaptor.recyclerViewAdapterListener{
private int pos;


@Override
 public void onDeviceConnect(data,position){
  pos = position; 
 }
```

`

Comment: pos = position will get the last that's problem , because I don't want to get the last position.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `position` with `holder.getAdapterPosition()`

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     //here I call onDeviceConnect
     holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View view) {
         listener.onDeviceConnect(data, holder.getAdapterPosition());
   }
```

Or you can also `setOnClickListener` in the constructor of the `ViewHolder` class